# How to make a fully functional customizable TextField border in MacOS?

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm working on an app that targets both iOS and macOS. This TextField works fine in iOS, but has a problem in MacOS.

```
TextField("Price", text: $priceText)
                    .focused($priceFocus)
                    .labelsHidden()
                    .padding(3)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
                            .stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 1)
                    )
```

[image: Screenshot of text field.]

In MacOS if I tap the field anywhere in the empty space in the TextField after the text, then the field does not respond. I have to click directly on top of existing text to edit the text. If I have an empty field, entering text is almost impossible. I have to click a tiny area at the beginning of the text field.

The bug is related to the .overlay.

If I use RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle the TextField functions fine, but does not display the way I want. The default RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle is much fainter than I want.

[image: Screenshot of two field styles.]

I've filed feedback with Apple: FB12873287 about this bug. This is a bug in MacOS 13 and 14.

I've tried writing my own TextFieldStyle. It has the same bug as long as I have a RoundedRectangle in it.

```
struct FormFieldBorderStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
        configuration
            .padding(3)
            .cornerRadius(4)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
                    .stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 1))
    }
}
```

Is there any way to customize RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle to make it more visible?

Is there any way to put a rounded rectangle border around a textfield without using .overlay?

P.S. the .border modifier on TextField has the same bug in macOS SwiftUI described above as .overlay.

Answer (score 0):

Using a ZStack with a geometry reader and removing the border from your textField gives you a lot of control by layering objects behind it. Can be a bit time consuming but might be what you’re looking for.

```
            GeometryReader { geo in
            ZStack {
                if priceFocus == .firstPrice {
                    // Focused look
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .frame(height: 22)
                        .frame(maxWidth: geo.size.width)
                        .cornerRadius(6)
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(height: 18)
                        .frame(maxWidth: geo.size.width - 4)
                        .cornerRadius(4)
                } else {
                    // No focus look
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .frame(height: 22)
                        .frame(maxWidth: geo.size.width)
                        .cornerRadius(6)
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(height: 20)
                        .frame(maxWidth: geo.size.width - 2)
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                }
                
                TextField("Price", text: $priceText)
                    .focused($priceFocus, equals: .firstPrice)
                    .labelsHidden()
                    .padding(3)
                    .textFieldStyle(.plain)
                    .offset(x:2)
            }
        }
```